# How do I make rustc-link-search relative to the project location?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am creating a Rust wrapper around a C library. I've put the C libraries in the `lib` directory and I am using `build.rs` to tell the compiler where to find the libraries to link with:

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=wrapped-lib");
println!(r"cargo:rustc-link-search=lib\");
```

This works fine when I build the library, but downstream libraries which depend on the wrapper library get compilation failures:

```
error: could not find native static library `wrapped-lib`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?
```

The problem seems to be with:

```
println!(r"cargo:rustc-link-search=lib\");
```

When compiling a client library, this does not point at `repository\checked_out_project\lib` but instead seems to be looking locally, because specifying the absolute path in the dependency works:

```
println!(r"cargo:rustc-link-search=C:\users\id\.cargo\..\lib\");
```

I also have instructed Cargo to include the `lib` directory in the wrapper-lib as follows:

```
include = ["lib/**/*"]
```

How do I tell the compiler to look relative to the dependency, not the project being built? I thought that this should work:

```
println!(r"cargo:rustc-link-search=lib\");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Manually.

A good example of this is the [`winapi`](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/) crate.  It has a pair of sub-crates for import libraries, each of which has a build script and a `lib` directory.  The [build script for the `i686` crate](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/blob/dev/i686/build.rs) contains the following:

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let dir = env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", Path::new(&dir).join("lib").display());
}
```

Comment: @Shepmaster Unless Cargo is parsing the build script's stdout as raw binary data, it won't matter.  To avoid `display`, you'd also have to avoid all regular string-based formatting and output.

Comment: I mean, I'm sure the Cargo authors talked to the Rust authors (because they are the same people), and the Rust authors are the ones who created `Path` and `PathBuf` to be separate from `&str` and `String`. I'd hope (but wouldn't hold my breath) that Cargo does try a little bit harder. You wouldn't have to abandon all regular formatting though, just for the variables that needed it. It's also a shame that there's no obvious `panic` if the path cannot be display-formatted, which would cause any errors I'm worried about to happen in an obvious way.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work for you:

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=./lib");
```

It`s going to be relative path, without any env variables.